# Im asking the user to open a file, though the file is added by 2 ascci values

Tags: python

I have got the code for changing the assci value but for tab there is a block, it is there because in the file there are horizontal tabs. I don't know how to get the horizontal tabs to display rather than the block.

This is my code.

```
print('          Decode Messages Here!')
infile = open(openfile)
line = infile.read()
new_line = ''
for i in range(len(line)):
    if line[i] ==  ' ':
        new_line += ' '
    else:
        new_line += chr(ord(line[i])+2)

infile.close()
```

I also had to get rid of the quotation marks and replace it with a space but I dont know how to get the tab to work

Comment: You probably only want to add 2 to ascii codes greater than 32: `if ord(line[i]) > 32: new_line += chr(ord(line[i])+2) else: new_line += line[i]`

Answer (score 2):

Check if the character is `\t`, just like you do for space. You should also skip over newline as well.

```
for char in line:
    if char in {' ', '\t', '\n'}:
        new_line += char
    else:
        new_line += chr(ord(char)+2)
```